# admin console GQL query: index not found when ordering on date

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

My datastore-indexes.xml looks like this:

```
<datastore-index kind="Book" ancestor="false" source="auto">
    <property name="^i" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="nurInRange2" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="firstModificationDate" direction="desc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

The datastore admin console actually shows this under Data / Datastore indexes:

```
^i ▲ , nurInRange2 ▲ , firstModificationDate ▼ : serving
```

But yet, when I go to the Datastore Viewer and execute a `by gql` query:

```
SELECT * FROM Book where nurInRange2 = True  order by firstModificationDate DESC
```

I get the following response:

```
no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
    - kind: Book
    properties:
      - name: nurInRange5
      - name: firstModificationDate
        direction: desc
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Is there anything wrong with my index formulation?

Comment: what's the ^i property (in the index) why is it there? its not part of the suggested indexed. you need a new index without it.

Comment: @Shay: ^i property is (most probably) a generated property of Objectify, needed for polymorphism: http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Implementation_Considerations

Comment: 10x @PeterKnego I never used Objectify.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'firstModificationDate' in your filter if you want to sort on it.

See [Restrictions on Queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Restrictions_on_Queries) for more info.